# Sed - remove last two character quotes and comma

Tags: unix, sed

i wanted to keep only the 10.100.52.11 and delete everything else, 10.100.52.11 keeps changing so i don't want to hard code it

The original output was as below

```
 "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.52.111",
```

I tried the below command and removed "PrivateIpAddress": "

```
sudo aws ec2 describe-instances --filter  Name=tag:Name,Values=bip-spark-es-worker1 |grep PrivateIpAddress |head -1|sed 's/^[ ^t]*\"PrivateIpAddress\"[:]* \"//g'
```

so the output for the above command now is

```
10.100.52.111",
```

I want to delete even the ending quotes and comma.

I tried with `["].$` and also `\{2\}.$`  did not work. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let sed do all the work.  You don't need grep or head:

```
   sed -n '/"PrivateIpAddress": /{s///; s/[",]//g; p; q}'
```

Comment: Thanks . but there is a space present between the "PrivateIpAddress"
   "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.52.111",

Answer (score 1):

If content within `"` do not have `"` themselves,

```
grep PrivateIpAddress |head -1|sed 's/^[ ^t]*\"PrivateIpAddress\"[:]* \"//g'
```

can be replaced with

```
awk -F\" '/PrivateIpAddress/{print $4; exit}'
```

- `-F\"` use `"` as field separator
- `/PrivateIpAddress/` if line matches this string

  - `print $4` print 4th field which is `10.100.52.111` for given sample
  - `exit` will quit as only first match is required

Answer (score 1):

some awk proposals

```
echo '"PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.52.111",'| awk -F: '{print substr($2,3,13)}'
10.100.52.111
echo '"PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.52.111",'| awk -F\" '{print $4}'
10.100.52.111
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

```
$ echo "\"PrivateIpAddress\": \"10.100.52.111\", "
"PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.52.111", 

$ echo "\"PrivateIpAddress\": \"10.100.52.111\", " |grep -Po '(\d+[.]){3}\d+'
10.100.52.111

$ echo "\"PrivateIpAddress\": \"10.100.52.111\", " |grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]+[.]){3}[[:digit:]]+'
10.100.52.111
```